# Postgres.app says "Running on Port 5432" but psql command fails

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgres.app, and when I open it, the menu bar icon says "Running on Port 5432". But when I click on the "Open psql" menu option, I see the following message:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql ; exit;
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
logout

[Process completed]
```

Any ideas what might be up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely in a different location, there are a few ways to fix this.

1. When connecting use tcp instead of unix sockets (`-h localhost`)
2. Specify the correct socket while connecting (you can get it with: `netstat -ln | grep PGSQL`)
3. Change the location of the socket by modifying your postgresql.conf and changing the `unix_socket_directory` variable.

Comment: Aaaand putting my computer to sleep and waking it back up seemed to fix it. When I restarted Postgres.app I got a dialogue box to "Accept" or "Deny" network connections. Weirdly I had only seen this box as a flicker before - thought I was seeing things. I clicked "Accept" of course, and all was fine. Very strange. Nonetheless I am accepting your answer and upvoting Cody Caughlan's as well - I appreciate the tips!

Comment: You can also specify the socket directory to connect to by giving a path to `psql`, eg `psql -h /var/pgsql/socket` or whatever your socket dir is.

Answer (score 1):

According to:

http://postgresapp.com/documentation

Try connecting on the command line with:

```
$ psql -h localhost
```